# jQuery / JavaScript Parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that you can use jQuery to get the parent element like so:

```
$("li").parent().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

But I was wondering, how can I select *only* one parent element without passing a CSS element. For example, just `.parent()` without the `li` so it doesn't select all the `li` elements on the page. The reason for this is because I need to build a code that works inside of a stream of content feed and each stream item will have the same CSS and HTML structure so I won't be able to give each element its own class.

Comment: And how are you suppose to select this specific element?! Your question is missing some context, it currently doesn't make sense

Comment: How do you want to access a parent of an element if you don't have the element itself?

Comment: If you use this in event handler then you can use `$(this).parent().css({...});`

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to indicate within an onclick event that items parent itself

Comment: In an `onclick`, you'd do `$(this).parent()`, as you'd learn in any beginner tutorial.

Comment: @Brigitte `this` refers to clicked DOM node

Comment: thank you! (this).parent!!! wow so easy!

Comment: Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com jquery how to select parent of clicked element](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+how+to+select+parent+of+clicked+element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JQuery to select parent element of "this" (element clicked)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119529/use-jquery-to-select-parent-element-of-this-element-clicked)

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to select parent element of `li` elements without using `li` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `#eq(n)` method on the jQuery object to select a specific `li` element at an index. But it sounds to me like you're trying to apply the CSS styles when an event happens, like a click on a `li`.

In case you know the index of the element you wanna style the parent of:

```
// gets the element at index 6
$("li").eq(6).css({color: "red", border: "2px solid red"});
```

If there's a click or hover event or whatever, something like:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  // `this` refers to the `li` that got clicked.
  $(this).parent().css({color: "red", border: "2px solid red"});
});
```

Let me know how it works out for you!

Comment: well it would be a feed of content, so listing an index would not work. I think the above comment to use (this).parent when clicking an element should work

Comment: That's what I figured — I wasn't sure — which is why I included both versions.